# Rails: update_attributes not updating all attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, update-attributes

I have a simple model called Discussion which has a boolean column called resolved.

In my form, I have the following code

```
<%= form_for(@discussion) do |d| %>
...
<%= d.check_box :resolved %>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller, I have the following:

```
def update
  @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:id])
  if @discussion.update_attributes(params[:discussion])
    etc...
  end
end
```

When I submit the form, I can see that the parameters are being sent to the server...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"AsGsRHwiVva/+kTrBs0IjLeZwj1ZmXBuKZr9Pg/N6Xk=", "discussion"=>{"shortdesc"=>"Talk about something.", "content"=>"Try to update check box.", "resolved"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Update Discussion", "id"=>"1"}
```

But the query doesn't include anything about updating that field.

```
AREL (14.9ms)  UPDATE "discussions" SET "content" = 'Try to update check box.', "updated_at" = '2011-07-18 17:53:50.783176' WHERE "discussions"."id" = 1
```

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are 4 reasons why this could be happening:

1. `resolved` is already set to true in the database.
2. You defined the `resolved=` method in your model and it no longer sets the attribute.
3. You have `attr_protected :resolved`.
4. You have `attr_accessible` but do not have `:resolved` in the list.

Comment: It was in fact number 4.  Good eye.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Another possibility is the `Discussion` model has validations or callbacks running on it that interfere with the update.

Comment: my case is 1. the value I set is null, so no value is updated.

Answer (score 1):

does your boolean column have a default? If it defaults to true - rails might not bother adding it to the set of attributes.

Alternatively, have you got attr_protected set for that column? if so - rails will never add that field to the attributes using update_attributes. You'll need to do that manually.

Comment: hmmmm i forgot to set the 'OR' condition in the model while specifying the defaults . Thanks God i found your post in start :P

Answer (score 1):

All,

I had recently begun rails and was taking over someone else's code and found another scenario that was not covered here that was getting me.

When using the style pointed to by this link, the params are formed in a separate method.  I had to update the "_params" method to add it to the allowable list.

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the element is sended it?
I mean, form element without checked the element are not sended, so you have to put an hidden checkbox for default false.

Comment: Rails solves this problem by having a hidden field before the checkbox with the same name with the false value. Anyway, that's not the case as you can see the `resolved` value is in the parameters hash.